# Reference request about St. John Vianney and the Miraculous Medal?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, st-john-vianney

I have come across on a couple of websites (one a blog), but never in a book, the following conversation between the Cure d'Ars and one of his penitents:

> "Do you remember that you went to a ball on such-and-such occasion?
>
> "Yes, I remember.
>
> "Do you remember that at a certain moment a handsome young man entered the ballroom? He was quite elegant, appeared very upright and danced with several young ladies?
>
> "Yes, I do.
>
> "Do you recall that you had a great desire to dance with him?
>
> "I recall that.
>
> "Do you recollect that you became sad because he didn’t ask you to dance?
>
> "Yes, I do.
>
> "Do you remember that by chance you looked down at his feet and saw a strange blue light coming from them?
>
> "Yes. I remember.
>
> "That young man was none other than the devil who had taken that shape to tempt several of the young women there. He was unable to approach you because you are a Daughter of Mary protected by her, and you were wearing the Miraculous Medal.

I have never come across a legitimate reference for this conversation.

The two sites that I have seen this conversation recounted are:

- [*The Saint of the day* reflection on St  John Vianney](https://www.traditioninaction.org/SOD/j084sdCureArs_8-4.htm) by Prof. Plinio Corrêa de Oliveira
- [*A Catholic Life* article on St. John Vianney](https://acatholiclife.blogspot.com/2006/08/st-john-vianney.html)

*My Question is*: Can anyone who may be familiar with St. John Vianney and the Miraculous Medal provide me with a valid citation for this conversation? The aforementioned sites provide no reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Question Pertaining to St. John Vianney and the Miraculous Medal**

I have a great devotion to St. John Vianney and have read the works on the Curé D'Ars by [Mgr. Francis Trochu](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Trochu), the procurator of his cause in French.

If you can locate one of the first published works that were written by him for the beatification and/or canonization of Jean-Marie Baptiste Vianney you would find your references desired. Possibly later works could include the references you desire.

The procurators must publish the written works of his investigation which are heavily annotated with notes and sources, for the Sacred Congregation for the Causes of Saints.

If you are lucky, you may possibly find a biography about the *Curé D'Ars: St. Jean-Marie Baptiste Vianney* in English by the same author. Do not look at the abridged biographies of him. The greater number of pages, the greater the possibility that the notes you are looking for with be in that particular biographical works!

I know to be certain of what I am saying because I have personally read this original work on ***Curé D'Ars***, with the very notes and references you are desiring because I read this work some 30 years ago in French. If fact, at times I found the notes more interesting than the actual biography itself.

[image: The Curé D'Ars: St. Jean-Marie Baptiste Vianney]

[The Curé D'Ars: St. Jean-Marie Baptiste Vianney](https://www.amazon.ca/Cur%C3%A9-DArs-Jean-Marie-Baptiste-Vianney/dp/0895550202) by Mgr. Francis Trochu. This image is given as an example of Mgr. Trochu’s works only!

Comment: Thank you kindly for your very thoughtful response. Alas, the conversation is not to be found in the TAN book by Trochu which you have posted the cover. Before posting the question, I have literally gone through every word of that book. That is not to say that it is not in the original French version by Trochu, which unlike the TAN book (a retypeset version of the 1927 Burns and Oates edition), it may be available in a PDF online. Alas, I do not read French very well and so did not check that avenue.

Comment: However, if you know of a particular French version that definitely contains the alluded to conversation, I would be grateful if you let me know. Perhaps even Catherine Lassagne's ``Petite Memorie'' might have it, but my French is so bad, I wouldn't know it if I saw it. Thank you again for responding to my question.

Comment: @I.Chekhov I can check out a private Catholic library for you. But it may take some time, as Covid-19 guidelines are in place at our local seminary.

Comment: That's very kind of you but I don't want to cause you any inconvenience. I am in the process of writing a book that focuses on what the Cure of Ars has to say to us today; the year-long project is winding down  but there is still a fair amount of editorial work to be done. Though I would like to include the conversation on the Miraculous Medal, I still have some time to find a valid reference. If you ever come across one in your travels, I would be grateful if you would send it my way. Thanks again.